# Three.js ParticleSystem flickering with large data

Tags: graphics, graph, 3d, three.js, webgl

Back story: I'm creating a Three.js based 3D graphing library. Similar to [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/), but 3D. It's called *graphosaurus* and the source can be found [here](https://github.com/frewsxcv/graphosaurus/). I'm using Three.js and using a single particle representing a single node in the graph.

This was the first task I had to deal with: given an arbitrary set of points (that each contain X,Y,Z coordinates), determine the optimal camera position (X,Y,Z) that can view all the points in the graph.

My initial solution (which we'll call Solution 1) involved calculating the bounding sphere of all the points and then scale the sphere to be a sphere of radius 5 around the point 0,0,0. Since the points will be guaranteed to always fall in that area, I can set a static position for the camera (assuming the FOV is static) and the data will always be visible. This works well, but it either requires changing the point coordinates the user specified, or duplicating all the points, neither of which are great.

My new solution (which we'll call Solution 2) involves not touching the coordinates of the inputted data, but instead just positioning the camera to match the data. I encountered a problem with this solution. For some reason, when dealing with *really* large data, the particles seem to flicker when positioned in front/behind of other particles.

Here are examples of both solutions. Make sure to move the graph around to see the effects:

- [Solution 1](http://froosky.rwell.org/graphosaurus/examples/eve/)
- [Solution 2](http://froosky.rwell.org/graphosaurus-alt/examples/eve/)

You can see the diff for the code [here](https://github.com/frewsxcv/graphosaurus/pull/53/files)

Let me know if you have any insight on how to get rid of the flickering. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like z-fighting. You need to decrease the far-plane for the camera.

Comment: @Charlotte I tried decreasing the far plane significantly and didn't see any differences. Any other ideas?

Comment: After fiddling around with the near/far values, I needed to increase the near value and the far value. Maybe I'd need to generate these values dynamically depending on the inputted data.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. The difference between the near and far plane should be as small as possible without clipping your models to avoid z-fighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my `near` value for the camera was too low and the `far` value was too high, resulting in "z-fighting". By narrowing these values on my dataset, the problem went away. Since my dataset is user dependent, I need to determine an algorithm to generate these values dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the sol#2 the flickering only occurs when the camera is moving. One possible reason can be that, when the camera position is changing rapidly, different transforms get applied to different particles. So if a camera moves from `X` to `X + DELTAX` during a time step, one set of particles get the camera transform for `X` while the others get the transform for `X + DELTAX`.

If you separate your rendering from the user interaction, that should fix the issue, assuming this is the issue. That means that you should apply the `same transform` to all the particles and the edges connecting them, by locking (not updating ) the transform matrix until the rendering loop is done.